# restore open programs across reboot/restart in mint?

Tags: linux

When I used to turn off my Windows 8.1  machine all my programs would automatically save before shutdown and open again when the OS restarted.

Is there a way to do this in mint?

Answer (score 0):

This is callled *session management*.  See `man xsession` for the basic implementation, though various window management systems (Gnome, Cinnamon, KDE, ...) sometimes place a management UI on top of this, so a full answer to your question depends on which desktop environment within Linux Mint you are using.